# Google Doc's Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Let me start by saying this is my first time using google scripts.

I have a sheets function I found by searching and after a little editing got functioning.  It sends an email about a status update, on a row, based on a menu selection.  I would also like it to add text to a column titled "Email Sent" (column O if that matters) when the email is sent out.

This is the current script:

```
function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function emailStatusUpdates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var userEmail = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("email")).getValue();
  var subject = "Helpdesk Ticket #" + row;
  var body = "We've updated the status of your ticket.\n\nStatus: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Status")).getValue();
  body += "\n\nNotes: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Notes")).getValue();
  body += "\n\nResolution: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Resolution")).getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name:"Help Desk"});
}

function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [{name:"Send Status Email", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Help Desk Menu", subMenus);
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty trivial. You would use the `setValue` method on a range in the `emailStatusUpdates` function.

```
var confirmText = "Email sent at " +
  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),
                       "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("email date")).setValue(confirmText);
```

I'm using your function `getColIndexByName` to avoid hard-coding column "O" in the code. You will have to make sure the header for column O matches what we're passing to this function.